# PRC failed; HTTP 413 , How can I separately push commit

Tags: git, github

It seems my commit is too large(total is 238.34 Mib), so I can't push to GitHub. How can I separate my commit?

Many Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTTP status code 413 indicates that your request is too large.  However, GitHub does not emit that status code for the service that handles Git connections over HTTPS.

Instead, you are likely using an antivirus or firewall other than the built-in ones (Windows Defender or Windows Firewall), or you are using a proxy or TLS middlebox which is intercepting your connections.  You should uninstall that antivirus or firewall completely and reboot, switching to the default instead, or switch to a network without that proxy or middlebox.  Alternatively, you can use SSH to push.

Comment: Thank you, I don't use a firewall or any antivirus, but I will reboot my computer and try later.  If still doesn't work, I will use SSH instead.